# Django Autofill form from list

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

Hello and thank you in advance,

I am trying to create a django form where I can select a value from an existing list.  I would like the field(s) to be autofilled as the user types his selection.

Can someone please point me to a tutorial, or how to, or some other information on how to make this happen?

Thank you,

dp

Comment: Django is a backend framework, not a frontend display mechanism, so Django has no idea what they are typing unless the applet/javascript tells it so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For learning how to do it from scratch with JQuery see [here](http://readncode.com/blog/AJAX-Autocomplete-Search-with-Django-and-jQuery/)

For making your life easier and automating this stuff see [django-ajax-selects](https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this library: https://github.com/theatlantic/django-chosen