# Show suggestions, django-form

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to write a searchform and I'm looking for a way to show suggestions of autofills that updates while you're writing. If I write 'New', I would like for it to show cities starting with 'New' in a dropdown list. Sort of the same way it does in google maps. Any suggestions?

This is my forms.py so far.

```
class SearchForm(Form):
    query = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.TextInput())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        cities = City.objects.all().order_by('name')
        self.fields['query'].choices = [(city.pk, city) for city in cities]
```

Comment: you have to do it with ajax. probably https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects will help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django Autofill form from list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475727/django-autofill-form-from-list)

Comment: Once you come up with a simple AJAX solution, if you care about performance, you may want to consider caching so that you don't make unnecessary server queries.  I described a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130676/how-to-reuse-jquery-ui-autocomplete-cached-results-when-appending-search-term